# Data manipulation in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to handle what I want to do in PowerShell.

I have this data in a text file:

```
"0003233","9/1/2017","0241902","$12,145.05"    
"FGENERAL","MY VENDOR","VENDOR COMPANY INC.",""    
"1","Check(s)","Checks Total:","$12,145.05"
```

I want to run PowerShell to make it look like this:

```
"0003233","9/1/2017","0241902","MY VENDOR","VENDOR COMPANY INC.","$12,145.05"
```

I have experience with simpler data manipulation, but I'm stumped on how to handle this one.  Can anyone suggest something?

Thanks

Comment: Will the data always be exactly like you displayed it up there?

Comment: Yes, it's always arranged like that.  Always the same order just different values.

Comment: and your getting it from a file directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get contents from file,

Use select-string with regex to split the string at the quotes.

Use the string array to build your final output.

```
$string = Get-Content "C:\Test\Test.txt"

$StringArray = Select-String "([`"'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1" -input $string -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches.Value}

write-output "$($StringArray[0]),$($StringArray[1]),$($StringArray[2]),$($StringArray[5]),$($StringArray[6]),$($StringArray[11])"
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you so much!  I figured it would be more difficult than I was hoping.

Comment: So what if I had a whole file full of these?   Just the same 3 lines over and over.  How could I parse them all out?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Get-Content` to read the text file in. At that point you have an array of lines. If you know for sure the order of the lines are the same each time then you can create a new array or string, depending on your needs, from the text file array.

```
$textFile = Get-Content -Path "C:\..." #reads in the text file
$lineOne = $textFile[0].Split(",") #splits the first line based on commma, repeat for each line
$formattedLine = $lineOne[0] + "," $lineOne[5] #creates new string
```

This would allow you to restructure the data into the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Data = Import-Csv .\Data.txt -Header 0,1,2,3
$Data[0]."0", $Data[0]."1", $Data[0]."2", $Data[0]."3", $Data[1]."1", $Data[1]."2", $Data[2]."3"  -Join ","
```